# How to find every events associated with a textbox in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a serious trouble with textboxes in a page which I've been asked to modify. When ever I tried to start typing something on the textboxes the **span** which is a sibling of the textboxes becomes hidden. Mine is an ASP.NET application which depends on lots of JS files in its master page and also in this page which is a child page of the master. So there is some functions or events where the span next to textbox to get hidden when ever **key press** event in textbox occurs. I'm not able to find what is that event or function associated with the textbox. Its on a function on the child page. So its tough to identify that particular event or function which hides the **span**

As you can see in bellow screen shot the span which is sibling of the textbox becomes hidden when I typed something.. So how can we isolate that hidden function or event associated with textboxes in general in my application (I guess so)

[image]

**A way I tried in firebug**
[image]

Comment: You can find the events associated with the element if you right click on the element and inspect element and you can find EventListeners tab, where you can find associated events w.r.t that particular element...

Comment: I used to check it on chrome developer tools. When you inspect an element you can see the event listeners attached in the right column.

Comment: Most likely that you have an 'onkeypress' or similar   handler on your textbox. Try logging the handler in the console to verify.

Answer (score 3):

You can find all javascript listeners on an element with this code :

```
$._data($('#element')[0], "events");
```

If you have an old version of jQuery, this code will works too :

```
$('#element').data("events");
```

In some browser, the web developper tools can show the attached javascript listener (try to press F12).

Keep in mind that a listener can be bind on an element or on any of its parents. So if you have an undefined result with the element itself, check the parents too.

Comment: Sorry, I tried both jquery way you mentioned on firebug, but both return undefined...  Or is that wont work in firebug?

Comment: It is supposed to works in any javascript console. Firebug, firefox default console, chrome. Even on internet explorer.

Comment: Sorry, please have a look at an edit I made on the question. I added a screen shot of firebug console. Also I specified another jquery which shows the Textbox length is 1. So it exists but returns nothing

Comment: Remove the second line. Firebug display the result of the last line only.

Comment: I executed first line, then entered second line and executed. As in the image the result of first line is shows as undefined.

Comment: I tried all the parents of the textbox upto all levels. But all returned Undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) add-on with Firefox.
After installing it, right click on the text box -> select Inspect Element -> click on the little 'ev' button to view the related events.

Here's an example with Google's search box:
[image: FireQuery on Google search]